# Resolved exception caused by Handler execution

Tags: angularjs, spring

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token
>
> 2019-02-26 13:47:12.697  WARN 2510 --- [nio-9009-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token
>
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 83] (through reference chain: ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User["roles"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token
>
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 83] (through reference chain: ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User["roles"])

I get this error when with angularjs I try in the roles field which is an array, to transfer the value as an array, but something is not correct

```
 <div class="bloc" >
    <select ng-model="user.roles">
        <option value= {"ROLE_USER"}>ROLE_USER</option>
        <option value= {"ROLE_SUPPORT"} >ROLE_SUPPORT</option>
        <option value={"ROLE_ADMIN"} >ROLE_ADMIN</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I just can not pass this value into this field, maybe I incorrectly pass the value to be saved in the roles field?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bloc" >
<select ng-model="role" ng-change="selectRole()">
    <option ng-value="ROLE_USER">ROLE_USER</option>
    <option ng-value="ROLE_SUPPORT">ROLE_SUPPORT</option>
    <option ng-value="ROLE_ADMIN">ROLE_ADMIN</option>
</select>
```

```
$scope.role = undefined;


        $scope.selectRole = function() {
            $scope.user.roles = [$scope.role];
        }
```

this fixed my mistake